# DataTables and Hyperlink group button

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I've place a bootstrpa button group, in an actios column in my DataTable. The button consists of three options, each option calls a separate function, passing in the value of an Id.

This is all set up, in the ColumnDefs portion of the datatable like this:

```
   "columnDefs": [
             { "visible": false, "targets": 7 },
             { "visible": true, "targets": 8 },
              {
                  "targets": 8,
                  "visible": true,
                  "searchable": false,
                  "sortable": false,
                  "data": "download_link",
                  "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {

                      return '<div class="btn-group" role="group">' +
                          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action<span class="caret"></span>' +
                          '</button>' +
                          '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">' +
                         '<li><a href="javascript:viewMessage(' + data + ');">View</a></li>' +
                         '<li><a href="javascript:completeMessage(' + data + ');">Complete</a></li>' +
                          '<li><a href="javascript:approveMessage(' + data + ');">Approve</a></li>' +
                          '</div>';
                  }
              }
            ]
```

My viewMessage function doesn't even get called, as I'm getting an Uncaught ReferenceError 'value' is not defined.

If I omit the 'data' value, my method is fired.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to be completely sure without seeing the code for the targeted functions, for example `viewMessage`, but I think the problem is that you are not quoting `data`. Do this instead :

```
'<li><a href="javascript:viewMessage(&quot;' + data + '&quot;);">View</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="javascript:completeMessage(&quot;' + data + '&quot;);">Complete</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="javascript:approveMessage(&quot;' + data + '&quot;);">Approve</a></li>' +
```

without the quotes, `data` is inserted as it was reference to a variable. If `data` is "test", the result would be

```
<a href="javascript:viewMessage(test);">View</a>
```

and `test` does not exists in the scope as variable, hence *Uncaught ReferenceError 'value' is not defined* (I guess you refer to the passed parameter as `value` in the three functions.